# Should I have two seperate mongoDB instances?

Tags: mongodb

My server queries the db often. 
But more often than not, the query retrieves unchanged data.
Therefore I would like to create and store a cached result.

My main mongoDB is stored in a remote address, and therefore takes slightly longer to respond as compared to a local mongoDB instance. I thought it would be beneficial to have therefore an additional, smaller, more static mongoDB running on localhost.

Such that, real-time queries will run on the remote main DB, and smaller, time efficient queries will run on the cached collections in localhost for optimizing speed.

- Is this something that can be done?
- Is it something people recommend to avoid?
- How would I set two connections, one to my main remote server and one
  to my local server?

**This seems wrong to me**

```
    var mongooseMain = require ('mongoose');
    var mongooseLocal = require ('mongoose');
    mongooseMain.connect(mainDBInfo.url);
    mongooseLocal.connect(localDBInfo.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

In principal, you have the right idea! Caching is a big part of building performant web applications.

First of all, MongoDB wants to cache everything it's using in memory and has a very well designed system of deciding what to keep in memory and what to toss out of it's cache. When an object is asked for that is not in it's cache, it has to read it from disk. When MongoDB reads from disk instead of memory it's called a page fault.

Of course, this memory cache is on a remote server so you still have network latency to deal with.

To eliminate this latency, I would recommend saving the serialized objects you read from often, but rarely write to, in [Redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis). This is what Redis was built to do. It's basically a dictionary (key:value) which you can easily `SET` and `GET` from. You can run redis-server easily on your local machine and even use `SETEX` to set your objects to the dictionary with some unique key and an expiry for when it should be evicted from the cache.

You can also manually evict objects from the cache whenever they do get updated (I would recommend re-writing them to the cache at this moment). Then, whenever you need an object, just make sure you always try to read from your cache first and fall back to MongoDB if the cache returns `null` for a key.

Check it out and good luck with your application!